# How to loop executable argument for Ant <exec>?

Tags: ant

I have a command that will receive option that can be used multiple times, for example

```
$./myprogram --param a --param b --param c --param d
the input param
a
b
c
d
```

I want to execute this program using Ant `<exec>` and `ant-contrib`'s `<for>`.

Instead of looping the `<exec>`, like below

```
<for list="a,b,c,d" param="var">
    <exec executable="myprogram">
       <arg value="--param"/>
       <arg path="@{var}"/>
    </exec>
</for>
```

I tried this looping the `param`, like below

```
<exec executable="myprogram">
    <for list="a,b,c,d" param="var">
       <arg value="--param"/>
       <arg path="@{var}"/>
    </for>
</exec>
```

But it doesn't work. The terminal returns this message

```
exec doesn't support the nested "for" element.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100579/how-to-transform-property-into-multiple-arguments-to-exec-task), and it works although it's longer than what I thought

```
<property name="arg_list" value="a,b,c,d"/>
<resources id="arguments">
    <mappedresources>
        <string value="${arg_list}" />
        <filtermapper>
            <replacestring from="," to=" --param "/>
        </filtermapper>
    </mappedresources>
</resources>
<property name="arguments" value="--param ${toString:arguments}" />
<exec executable="myprogram">
    <arg line="${arguments}"/>
</exec>
```